# how to run post build task in jenkins slave?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a requirement that i need to run postbuild task on jenkins slave machine.I cannot use the property "**Restrict where this project can be run**" because no need to run entire project in slave.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilites:

1. Use jenkins pipeline

   `node("master") {
     stage("do main build thing") {
       // do something
     }
   }
   node("slave") {
     stage("do postbuild") {
       // do post build task
     }
   }`

   More information about the jenkins pipeline https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/
2. Use a second job
   You can configure a job which only executes the post build task and restrict it to the slave with "Restrict where this project can be run". On the main job you add a post build action: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: Can i use this pipeline functionality only to postbuild scripts ? or should i need to add pipeline code for entire project ?

Comment: do you have to refer to node by node name are can your access it by its lable?